# Select query case when with condition with LinQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to add a condition in `Select` query with `r.Field<bool>("isDefault") != false` when `DetailNo` equals to `ZZZZZ`, I can get all codes as `r.Field<string>("Code")` with `Distinct`.

For example:

```
Code | DetailNo | isDefault                 Code | DetailNo | isDefault
IP6  |   ZZZZZ   | true                      IP6  |   AAAAA   | false
IP7  |   ZZZZZ   | true                      IP7  |   AAAAA   | false
IP7  |   ZZZZZ   | true                           |   AAAAA   | false
IP8  |   ZZZZZ   | false                     IP8  |   AAAAA   | true
IP7  |   ZZZZZ   | true                      IP7  |   AAAAA   | false
IP6  |   ZZZZZ   | true                      IP6  |   AAAAA   | false
IP8  |   ZZZZZ   | false                     IP8  |   AAAAA   | true
```

Result must be:

```
Code | DetailNo | isDefault                 Code | DetailNo | isDefault
IP6  |   ZZZZZ   | true                      IP6  |   AAAAA   | false
IP7  |   ZZZZZ   | true                      IP7  |   AAAAA   | false
                                             IP8  |   AAAAA   | true
```

---

```
int countItem = dt
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Code") != "")
                 .Select(r => r.Field<string>("DetailNo") == "ZZZZZ" ? r.Field<string>("Code") : r.Field<string>("Code") + r.Field<int>("TotalID"))
                 .Distinct()
                 .Count();
```

Comment: Why can't you add the second condition next to first one usingn the AND operator? something like this:
Where(r => r.Field<string>("Code") != "" && r.Field<bool>("isDefault"))

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein If I add the second condition so it may affect to the `r.Field<string>("Code") + r.Field<int>("TotalID")`. What I would like to do here is the condition only belongs to the `r.Field<string>("Code")`

Comment: Read my answer, if I understood well this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Where(r => r.Field<string>("Code") != "")
```

To this:

```
Where(r => r.Field<string>("Code") != "" && (r.Field<string>("Code") != "ZZZZ" || r.Field<bool>("isDefault"))))
```

So, you are filtering by code not empty and (code is equals to ZZZZ or IsDefault is true.

Comment: Thank you for your code. However, that one affected to the `r.Field<string>("Code")` which has `isDefault` column also.

Comment: I thought you wanted to achieve: Code is not ZZZZZ or IsDefault=true. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sadly, it affected to other select query as `r.Field<string>("Code")`. The example has been adjusted to put more additional information. Please take a look at that.

Comment: I don't see why my code would not give you the results you are expecting. Code!=ZZZZZ OR isDefault=true --> If code is ZZZZZ, then isDefault must be true (first resultset). If code is ZZZZZ, isDefault can have any value (second resultset).

Comment: For the first resultset, I still get `IP8  |   ZZZZ   | false`. That should not be there. The result must be have only `true` in `isDefault` column. For the second resultset, that works very well.

Comment: Did you copy and paste my answer? I wrote the code with 4 Zs so that's why. I have updated it, please try again.

Comment: Sorry that must be 5Zs. I have modified the example. So how to make it work with that?

Comment: It does not work as my desire because of the `DetailNo` instead of `Code`. I just change that and it works quite well. `.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Code") != "" && (r.Field<string>("DetailNo") != "ZZZZZ" || !r.Field<bool>("IsDefault")))`